# Why isn't this DIV centered?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that I want to keep centered and docked to the bottom of the page.  I've pretty much achieved that except that it lists to the right.  I've setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pR4P5/) to demonstrate the problem.

I suspect that I need to adjust margins but so far my attempts have been fruitless.  I tried adding:

```
margin: 0;
```

but nothing.  What am I missing?

Comment: The div is 100% wide...how would it not be centered? Are you referring to the anchor links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set left to 0 (zero) and box-sizing to border-box!

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/pR4P5/7/

```
#footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left:0;
}
```

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the little bit of space to the left, then I would think adding `left: 0;` would solve the problem.

```
#footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You need to watch though because you are setting the width to be 100% and also setting a border which makes the div wider than 100%.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is the default margin/padding on the body

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `border: 1px solid red;` and add `left: 0;` to `#footer`.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pR4P5/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `width: 100%` to

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

So it would become: http://jsfiddle.net/pR4P5/6/

Complete CSS:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Result would be 100% width while you can keep your border of 1px.
Note when defining width 100% and adding a border you might be better of adding `box-sizing` to it.
Also, `margin: 0;` to body is a great way to avoid headaches.

(`box-sizing: content-box;` - http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `margin: 0;` with `left: 0;`. This should lock the div onto the left of the page, centering it. I would also not use a border, that will add on some pixels to the width and height, making it less centered. I would instead use only `border-top: 1px solid red;`.

Hope I helped you solve your annoying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Paulie_D's answer is correct you need to add margin: 0 to the body. I'd imagine you think its not properly centred because of the border on the footer.

Try adding:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

to your footer element.

Answer (score 1):

To **Center** the div:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

To keep the **borders included** in the positioning, too:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pR4P5/8/

**Read More at:**

CSS Reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

box-sizing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing